# How to refer to subclass property in abstract shared implementation in abstract class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

For classes:

```
class Base(ABC):

    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param1 = param1
        
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method1(self):
        pass

    # @abstractmethod
    # def potentially_shared_method(self):
    #      ????

class Child(Base):
    
    def __init__(self, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        
    def some_method1(self):
        self.object1 = some_lib.generate_object1(param1, param2)

    def potentially_shared_method(self):
        return object1.process()
```

I want to move the `potentially_shared_method` to be shared in abstract calss, however it uses `object1` that is initialized in `some_method1` and needs to stay there.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how to corectly/pythonicly move the method implementation to ABC?

Comment: What method? What exactly doesn't work with what you have now? You can literally just move the method into the parent class

Answer (score 1):

If it's only *potentially* shared, it doesn't belong in the base class. You'd be breaking a few design principles.

What is a child class supposed to do for which the sharing doesn't make sense?

Also, you're introducing some temporal coupling; you can only call `potentially_shared_method` after `some_method1` has been called. That's not ideal because the users of your class might not realize that.

Also, if the method is *shared*, you probably don't want it to be *abstract* in your base class; with an abstract method you're really only sharing the signature; but it seems you'll want to share *functionality*.

Anyway. Here's some options:

1. Using Python's multiple inheritance, move `potentially_shared_method` into a `SharedMixin` class and have those children who share it inherit from `Base` *and* from `SharedMixin`. You can then also move `some_method1` into that `SharedMixin` class because it seems to me that those go together. Or maybe not...
2. Hide the access to `object1` behind a getter. Make the getter have a dummy implementation in the base class and a proper implementation in those child classes who actually create an `object1`. Then `potentially_shared_method` can be moved to `Base` and just refer to the getter.